# How to set shortcuts in Ubuntu (Gnome) for functionalities which are not available in Settings Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.10

In the `Settings` app in `Keyboard Shortcuts` are some functionalities where I can assign shortcuts. But I am missing some. Like "Switch to workspace 5". There is only "4". Or "Switch to next window" and "Switch to previous window".

I would like to know

1. How to set additional shortcuts?
2. Where to find a list with available functionalities in the Gnome Desktop which I can put on shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `dconf-editor`, navigate to /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/, and enjoy a wealth of possible actions to which you can assign your custom keyboard shortcuts. You can change the settings using `dconf-editor` or change the setting with a `gsettings` command. For example,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 "['<Super>F5']"
```

will setup <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for moving to the fifth workspace. Use `reset` and leave out the argument (`"['<Super>F5']"`) to reset the setting to factory default. Only a limited number of shortcut bindings are exposed in "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts".